# How to transform LiveData<List<User>> to LiveData<List<String>> in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have this ViewModel class:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyRepository() {
        myRepository = new MyRepository();
    }

    LiveData<List<String>> getUsersLiveData() {
        LiveData<List<User>> usersLiveData = myRepository.getUserList();
        return Transformations.switchMap(usersLiveData, userList -> {
            return ??
        });
    }
}
```

In `MyRepository` class a I have a method `getUserList()` that returns a `LiveData<List<User>>` object. How can I transform this object to `LiveData<List<String>>`, which basically should contain a list of strings (user names). My `User` class has only two fields, `name` and `id`. Thanks.

Comment: Take the variable `ArrayList` of type of `String`, then add all the `name` from `userList` to it by iterating over them, then return newly created list from callback.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I thought about that but isn't there any other possibility using `Transformations.switchMap`? Because I want to transform the LiveData<List<User>> object directly. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `Transformations.map`?

Comment: @SanlokLee I did not. How can use that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple `map`. `Transformation.switchMap` is for connecting to a different `LiveData`. Example:

```
    LiveData<List<String>> getUsersLiveData() {
        LiveData<List<User>> usersLiveData = myRepository.getUserList();
        return Transformations.map(usersLiveData, userList -> {
            return userList.stream().map(user -> user.name).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
    }
```